# Current distance of fixed or sticky element from top of screen

Tags: html, gwt, offset, fixed

I want to know the distance of a fixed or sticky element from the top of screen. This is the distance that doesn't change while the element is fixed even if you scroll up or down.
I tried getOffsetTop - Window.getScrollTop() but it doesn't seem to be correct..

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you inspect the element and note the `top` value?

Comment: @JessedeBruijne  I want to do this dynamically as I need to use it in the code and this value changes according to the element and time as it can be fixed at any location.